# print only changed row in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using a jqgrid and I have 3 columns that are editable all the time. I have a button that saves all the rows, but it is required to also print the changed rows so. Any idea how to make it do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: i am talking about the logic ... how to fetch the the changed rows onlyy

Comment: I am talking about the code!

Comment: @mermer please check  [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Because all your questions are either missing details or code